# UINavigationItem title location not updating on rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

This feels like a silly question but for the life of me, I can't figure it out. In short, I'm manually adding a navigation bar to my view and it contains a UINavigationItem.

I've added one UIBarButtonItem and I'm setting the title like so:

```
UIBarButtonItem * doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneTapped:)];
[doneButton setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:20 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
doneButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

self.navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];    
[self.navItem setLeftBarButtonItem:doneButton];
self.navItem.title = @"Help Directory";
[self.navBar setItems:@[self.navItem]];
```

This works fine will I reach this view controller. Problems start to arise during rotation. The title stays in the exact same location. Here's the portrait version:

[image]

Here's the landscape version:

[image]

This bug appears in earlier versions of the app, so it's not just an iOS 7 issue. Any advice on how to handle is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: The normal way to do this is get the navigation item, self.navigationItem, then populating it. Not setting it on the navBar. Try doing things in the normal flow and see what happens.

Comment: @BrianDouglasMoakley did you find a solution to this ?